# Понимают ли CreateFileW() и _wfopen() символы, состоящие из нескольких единиц

Tags: c, unicode, wchar-t

Подскажите, понимают ли названные функции строки, в которых какие-то символы кодируются не одним **wchar_t**, а несколькими? Или эти функции подразумевают, что символ всегда представлен одним **wchar_t**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эти функции подразумевают, что они имеют дело с [UTF-16LE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), в которой каждый символ записывается одним или двумя словами (суррогатная пара).